# Deleting memcache session from remote server

Tags: php, session, memcached

I need to limit only one login in that way, so that user can't login using one account multiple times at once. Also user can be logged on a different server, so I can't use session_destroy, I need to delete session "manually".

When using session with file storage it works fine, I delete file, login new user all works great. However when I use sessions with memcache, I can delete session from memcache, but further login in the same request is lost.

This is how I do it:

```
session_regenerate_id();
$session_id = session_id(); 

$m = new Memcache();
$m->connect('XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX', 11211);

$ans = $m->delete(SESSION_ID_OF_ALREADY_LOGGED_USER);

$query = "UPDATE activeLogins SET activeSession = '{$session_id}' WHERE userEmail = $safeEmail LIMIT 1";
$dbh->exec($query);

//Login new user...
```

Any idea what may be wrong?

Comment: Your login and session/memcache storing process is a bit unclear atm. Any more code snippets/explanations?

Comment: @ToBe Login is simple storing session variable to true. Memcache session storage is changed in php.ini by changing  `session.save_handler` and `session.save_path`. Additionally I found out this **When the page is complete it pushes the data now in the session to memcached. That last step is kind of critical, because it’s what’s controlling the expiry of the data within memcached.** Found [here](http://blog.preinheimer.com/index.php?/archives/334-Storing-Sessions-in-Memcache-how-everything-behaves.html)

Comment: Did you verify that your session using memcache is actually working? If in doubt, create a very small PHP file to rule out any errors in your code and try there with one session variable.

Comment: Session does work, I connected to memcache server over ssh, made query for particular session id and I do see results. As I said even this delete part works, but it's executed on the end of page, and every writing to session after delete statement is not stored in memcache. Hmm actually now that I think of, something is stored to session after delete statement (encoded data so can't really see) but user is not set as logged in... I'll test in external file. Tnx.

Comment: No, the session works if your session handler stores it's info AND it also retrieves it from memcache. You should never have to manipulate that memcache yourself as it could actually lead to corrupted session. Try to delete the variable inside the session though the normal session mechanisms. Do not access memcache directly.

Comment: But the point of this question is to log out DIFFERENT user, not myself. I don't see how I could achieve this other then deleting session from memcache directly. So basically I'm logging in myself and deleting session from OTHER user.

Comment: Your right, if you want to access other sessions, there's no other option for this. So to make it clear, the problme is that your delete call seems to delete not only the other session but your's as well?

Comment: That's what I though till now, but after running test in external script it looks like memcache and session works well. However my login works with file based sessions, but not memcache. I'll investigate this further and post update to the question. Ty for your time.

Comment: It's strange way to use memcache to store session ids... Anyway, how do you set this to memcache? And if to prevent double loggin in for every user it's better to do it in another way... Can't you imagine situation when memcache has reached memory limit and pops out already stored data including session ids? So, basically, this is breach in you system. Because for this case people MUST login twice... or more... One out, another in... Another in, first out... :) neverending story

Comment: I'm not storing session ids in memcache, complete session is stored in memcache, and key is session id.

Comment: You said that you wanted to logout the user immediately (+/- few secs) when they log into another computer. Can use say why? Is it because the content should no longer be visible on their previous computer, or just because they should not perform any actions on that computer anymore? In other words, what are the exact reasons to log the user out of the old computer?

Comment: It's because content should not be visible to the old logged user.

Comment: I don't think you can develop a reliable and scalable system that will do this in PHP/Javascript/HTML. That is why no general user management package implements this feature. The best you can do is poll the server to see if the session_id has changed.

Answer (score 2):

## Check the session id against what's stored in the database

As I understand it you want to restrict one user to one client machine. And that machine should be the last one that was logged into. I think you should be able to achieve this with a simple check on each page load.

From your question I can see that your database has a table called `activeLogins` containing at leat these fields: `activeSession` and `userEmail`.

From this I assume that it is the email address that uniquely identifies the user. So after a new login you have a `$session_id`, `$safeEmail` and the corresponding updated row in `activeLogins` table.

Now suppose the user didn't log out of an old machine? What will happen on the next page load there (before you update the `activeLogins` table)? Right, the `activeSession` will be different from the `$session_id` on that server. Remember that the new login changed it.

So all you need to do is check whether the `$session_id` matches the `activeSession` in  the `activeLogins` table.

I also would suggest to only update the `activeLogins` table after a new login, and not on each page load. Although it is not clear from your question whether or not you do this.

I'm not sure whether this does actually answer your question. It seems such a simple answer. However you question is not very clear. Are you really using the code you show us in that order on each page load?!

In response to all your answers I've looked for the best way to push notifications from the server to the client machine. One method you've mentioned yourself is ajax polling, but I think this is a bad practice and should not be used.

There is Ratchet (http://socketo.me) it gives you a continueous connection. You can simply remove the connection when another login is detected and react to that in the old client.

There's also a higher level interface for sending events from the server to a client:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Server-sent_events/Using_server-sent_events

But that's not supported in IE, so it is not generally usable.

You can also have a look at http://pusher.com

The point of all these suggestions is that you can efficiently push out a signal to a client, indicating that it should remove access to the site you're serving, without constantly polling.

Comment: Thank you for answering, I actually need to logout user immediately (+/- few secs), not only on page load, but I guess I could use what you said in a ajax request too... Codebase is much bigger and more complicated than in example I provided, but I wanted to narrow it down. I do not use exact code on EACH page load, it's used just when logging in. Simple answer, but I didn't think in that direction, I'll consider it, thanks.

Comment: Ah, I see. Well there isn't a sure way to control a browser on a client machine. But assuming the user has, and leaves, Javascript on, you could use a regular ajax calls (once every minute?) to check that the session_id hasn't changed. If it has you can remove the last page that was loaded and show a 'Logged into another client' message. Also make sure it is removed from the browser's history/cache. And the internet connection should be alive, of course, for this to work.

Comment: Another method would be to use Javascript to check if the user does anything. If they haven't done anything for some time you can remove the loaded page. This way you're only dependent on Javascript and not on the internet connection. This is not nice for the user. You could restrict it to critical page content only.